# Splash Screen only runs on first launch, and won't run on proceeding launches

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've created a splash screen and it runs as intended. However, once the app has launched once, and is launched again, the splash screen doesn't show. It only shows at first launch which is not how it's supposed to work. **I don't know how to resolve this.** The splash screen code is posted below.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.content.Intent;
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int SLEEP_TIMER = 5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        LogoLauncher logoLauncher = new LogoLauncher();
        logoLauncher.start();

    }

    private class LogoLauncher extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(1000 * SLEEP_TIMER);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
    }
```

**EDIT: I'm testing on my physical device in android studio. When I hit run and the app launches it works. If I quit the app and launch it again from my phone* It doesn't work**

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jstudios.main">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="MainApp"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="MainApp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**edit**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        Handler h =new Handler() ;
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();

            }, 5000);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what you mean by lunched once ? you quite the app and when your started again splash screen activity don't start and mainactivity fired ?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on my physical device in android studio. When I hit run and the app launches it works. If I quit the app and launch it again from my phone* It doesn't work

Comment: you quite the app by return or by home button ?

Comment: I quit the app by return and then clear it from the background essentially destroying it

Comment: ok , could you please post your manifest xml

Comment: sure I'm adding it to the post

Comment: tell me what heppen when you want to lunch it again ? if it crash what is the error in logcat

Comment: Only on the first launch of the app the splashscreen is shown. If I destroy the app and launch it again, all launches after the first app do not have the splash screen. There are no crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use handler to trigger your `startActivity`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
Handler h =new Handler() ;
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();

 }, 5000);
```

Or use `Timer`

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
   @Override 
   public void run() 
     { 
       Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.finish()
       }
     }, 5000);
```

Comment: What would I have to delete to put this in my code?

Comment: Logoluncher do not use that anymore

Comment: So delete everything besides the class and use this

Comment: yes , as i wrote , use hander instead of logoluncher thread class , and delete logoluncher

Comment: error cannot resolve symbol handler. Do I need to import something?

Comment: Yes , handler class , import android.os.Handler;

Comment: ok and the last line of your code has an unexecpeted token error

Comment: By the way the error was because you added another bracket } at the end ;) .glad i was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Sleeping the main thread to display a Splash screen is really a bad practice. 
The Splash screen should be displayed only while the app is loading (not a fixed time) to your main activity.

I recommend this approach, I've been using it in my own apps: 
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: Ok I'll try this and let you know